# Efficient way to fetch all archived WPMS blogs

Tags: multisite, list

is there a good and efficient way to fetch all WPMS blogs with archived set to true? Because there doesn't seem to be a function to get all blogs I have added the admin user to all blogs. Then I do a `get_blogs_of_user(1, false)`. This fetch all blogs that are active, but I'm looking for an efficient way to fetch all blogs that is archived.

I guess I can do something complicated e.g. call `get_blogs_of_user(1, true)` then `get_blogs_of_user(1, false)`, then find the difference and check if they have the archived bit set one by one, but is there some better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go directly to the database via `$wpdb`.

```
<?php
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE archived = 1" );
```

Or wrapped up in a function:

```
<?php
function wpse34731_get_archived_blogs()
{
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $wpdb ) ) return;

    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE archived = 1" );
    return $blogs;
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't return the name of the blog. You wouldn't know if it's easy to get that as well or do I need to go into each seperate options table? If so, this is not very efficent afterall.

Comment: It's stored in a separate table. Try using `get_blog_details` to fetch the info.